# How do I get all categories with at least one entry

Tags: categories, relations

I want all categories that have at least one entry that uses it.

Comment: Luke, this is an exact duplicate of Russ's question. Feel free to provide an answer over on that thread. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

`{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo({
    sourceElement: craft.entries.limit(null)
}) %}`

reference: https://craftcms.slack.com/archives/help/p1429030702000608

Comment: Is there a slack group? And if so, how would one get access to it?

Comment: @Douglas http://buildwithcraft.com/community

Comment: @carlcs don't know how i missed that. Thanks.